# Setting up aws ec2 first time - key-pair

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am following this [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/get-set-up-for-amazon-ec2.html#create-a-base-security-group) (see 'Create Key-Pair' section), and am getting an error when trying to perform `chmod` on my key pair.

The error I get is

> No such file or directory

file name is `abcd.pem`
my username is `xyz`
region is `seoul`

The above are just examples.

How should I construct the following command

`chmod 400 your_user_name-key-pair-region_name.pem`

should it be

`chmod 400 xyz-abcd-seoul.pem`??

Comment: You didn't add the tutorial link which you are following. Did you download the key pair on your local machine?

Comment: added, thanks for highlighting

Comment: `ls` is your friend. show us if the file is there.

Comment: sure is there i've checked

Answer (score 1):

You want to make sure you specify the full path to the file, not just the file name. The file name is just that, the file name - you only include your username and region if the region name and/or username are actually part of the filename.

Do a `dir` or `ls` and find out the actual filename as it exists on your local disk, and path, and then use that in your `chmod` command.